# Some sort of Padding Issue in IE with PRESTASHOP

Tags: internet-explorer, prestashop

There's a gap on my prestashop site under the shopping cart. Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated!

Site Link: http://stitchbystitch.co/catalogue/

Even reverting the entire theme to the original template does not take away this gap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page doesn't have a DOCTYPE. This means IE will go into quirks mode, which will indeed cause layout issues (and other quirks). Add a valid doctype to the top of you code.

If you don't know what this is, just copy the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

...and make it the very first line of your HTML code, right before the `<html>` tag.

Comment: In my HEADER.TPL, it says 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

Comment: When I load the page and view source, there is no doctype. The doctype you have in the template would be fine, but it isn't getting into your actual page.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but the links are not clickable (LOGIN, and SHOPPING CART) in IE as well.

Comment: Is there any advice you could give? Wise one

Comment: your site isn't loading at all for me now, so can't help. But if you're having a different problem, I suggest asking it as a new question on SO; you're more likely to get some useful help if you ask everyone rather than just one person.  :)